# MariaDB failed to start

Tags: mysql, linux, mariadb

I have to fix an issue on a VM for a website that use Mariadb technology. When I type "systemctl start mariadb", it shows :

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Here is what I have in error.log:

```
 2020-12-23 20:17:52 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-12-23 20:17:52 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't lock aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' for exclusive use, error: 11. Will retry for 30 seconds
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Could not get an exclusive lock; file is probably in use by another process' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control'
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error.
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process using the same InnoDB data or log files.
2020-12-23 20:18:23 0 [Note] InnoDB: Retrying to lock the first data file
2020-12-23 20:18:24 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
```

I have searched similar issues but solutions didn't work.
Thank you very much for your help.

Update : When I killall mysqld and I restart it, I have same issues

Comment: Your mariadb log is going to a different file. Look in /var/log/mysql or your settings in /etc/mysql/* for a setting for your log file. Edit question to include this. Remove journalctl output, ssh failed logins aren't relevant to you question.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: This is what you see in the log when another mariadb process is running. A `killall mysqld`  will terminate it eventually and then you can start with `systemctl start mariadb.service`

Comment: Same issue. I have the : ``` Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Comment: Well. its still running. Shutdown can be slow in the order of minutes, especially with `innodb_fast_shutdown=0` (not default) or large change. If its a small instance and still taking minutes it might be a bug, `kill -9` can stop it and let the start up process recover from it.